# How do I customize <select> display value?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a simple select:

```
<select>
    <option value="1" displayvalue="text 1">Very very long text 1</option>
    <option value="2" displayvalue="text 1">Very very long text 2</option>
    <option value="3" displayvalue="text 1">Very very long text 3</option>
</select>
```

When the select dropdown opens, you see the "Very very long text" as you normally should.

But, whenever I choose an option, and the dropdown closes, I want the `displayvalue` attribute to display in the select box instead of option's inner text (i.e *"text1"*).

What I am looking for is a something like:

```
option.onchange = function(){
    this.text = this.selectedOption.getAttribute("displayvalue");
}
```

I also can't seem to be able to find an `option` property that allows me to change the displayed text only, and not it's actual value.

Comment: First off, custom attributes should be `data-*` prefixed, second, you would need yet another to store the initially value, or else it will be gone the next time they open the select

Answer (score 1):

Target the selected option using [`selectedindex`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp)

```js
function gettext(sel) {
  alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('displayvalue'));
}
```

```html
<select onchange="gettext(this)">
    <option value="1" displayvalue="text 1">Very very long text 1</option>
    <option value="2" displayvalue="text 1" selected>Very very long text 2</option>
    <option value="3" displayvalue="text 1">Very very long text 3</option>
</select>
```

Using Dom listener

```js
$elem = document.querySelector('select')
$elem.addEventListener('change', gettext)

function gettext() {
  console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('displayvalue'));
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1" displayvalue="text 1">Very very long text 1</option>
  <option value="2" displayvalue="text 2" selected>Very very long text 2</option>
  <option value="3" displayvalue="text 3">Very very long text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And how do I tell the option to display *"text 1"* taken from `displayvalue` attribute instead of *"Very very long text 1"*?

Comment: Look at this snippet: https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/studioinsight/643734